# Kullback-Leibler Divergence vs Normalized Cross Correlation

Tags: time-series, similarities, kullback-leibler, cross-correlation

I have couple of time series data that I want to cluster. As I was looking for ways to calculate similarity for time series data, I came across couple of different similarity methods. What I am wondering is can Kullback-Leibler or normalized cross correlation be used to calculate similarity between two time series and if so how the results of these two methods should be interpreted?

Comment: Can you tell us how you propose to compare timeseries with Kullback-Leibler? or give a link/reference to examples